# Floating objects SHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, harmonic-oscillator, buoyancy

I've been trying to look for a derivation of the SHM due to the buoyant force, using proper unit vectors and so on, but to no avail.

I've attempted to do it, but after a certain while, I seem to be getting lost.

Let us denote the upward and downward unit vector as $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{d}$. Hence I can write the displacement vector as $\vec{x}=x_u\hat{u}/x_d\hat{d}$. Here $x_u,x_d$ are the components in the upward/downward directions and can be both positive and negative. Moreover, $x_u=-x_d$ and $\hat{u}=-\hat{d}$.

Suppose now, the liquid was initially at equilibrium. At first, we choose to take the upward direction as positive. Suppose, we now disturb the body, such that the submerged volume changes. The change in submerged volume can be written as :

$$\delta V=-Ax_u$$

This makes sense. Above the equilibrium, $x_u$ is positive. So, if we submerge the object further, $x_u$ becomes negative, and hence $\delta V$ becomes positive. This is exactly what we would expect. The submerged volume would increase if the object were pushed inward.

If we make this a vector, I suppose, we can say $\delta\vec{V}=-Ax_u\hat{u}$

Buoyant force $F_b$ is nothing but the weight of the displaced volume. Hence, $\vec{F}_b=\rho g\delta\vec{V}$

Thus, we can say : $$\vec{F}_b=-\rho gAx_u\hat{u}$$

Hence, net force in the upward positive direction is :

$$m\ddot{x}_u\hat{u}=-\rho gAx_u\hat{u}$$

Hence we have obtained our Harmonic oscillator.

However, what if I now take the downward direction as positive. If the displacement is positive along the downward direction, then the change in submerged volume becomes :

$$\delta V=Ax_d$$

Again this makes sense, $x_d$ is positive below the equilibrium. Hence, if $x_d$ increases, $\delta V$ must also increase.

In vector form, this should be $\delta \vec{V}=Ax_d\hat{d}$

In the upward positive direction, the change in volume vector had the opposite sign of the positive displacement vector. In the downward positive direction, the change in volume vector has the same sign as the new positive displacement vector.

So I don't see how to solve this system, by taking the downward direction to be positive. Any help would be highly appreciated. I suppose there is a mistake in how I'm changing the volume to a vector. However, I don't know how to solve this problem using a proper vector analysis. Most online derivations leave out the vectors, and this seems to confuse me.

Is $$\delta \vec{V}=A\vec{x}\,\,\,or\,\,-A\vec{x}$$

Moreover, $$\vec{F}_b=\rho g\delta\vec{V}\,\,\,or\,-\rho g\delta\vec{V}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For harmonic motion the (x) need to be measured from the equilibrium position. If (x) is chosen positive down, then an increase in (x) will cause an increase in the volume of water displaced. An increase in displacement will cause an increase in the upward (-) buoyant force.